# Typescript Error Cannot find name 'Observable' in @ionic-native/geolocation

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 2 and trying to use @ionic-native/geolocation, when I do ionic:serv on my project I got this Error:
Cannot find name 'Observable'.

[image: [1]: https://i.s]tack.imgur.com/dXNDc.png

This is my package.json file content:

```
{
  "author": "",
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.1.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.4",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "name": "Wakeb",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "ionic:build",
      "ionic:serve"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you dont seem to have added `@ionic-native/geolocation`. Which version gets installed?

Comment: Yes, you are right, i didn't add @ionic-native/geolocation, it's working now after adding it, Thank you.

Comment: ok.. added as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `node_modules` folder and running a fresh `npm install`. You may also want to try running `ionic plugin remove cordova-plugin-geolocation` and re-adding with `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`

Answer (score 0):

i didn't add @ionic-native/geolocation, it's working now after adding it, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json is missing `@ionic-native/geolocation`.

Do:

```
 npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

to install it.